# Writing Queries without the limit clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group

How can I rewrite the below query without the Limit clause?

```
SELECT project.title, 
       COUNT(project2manager.managerid) AS Cnt_Manager
FROM project2manager 
JOIN project ON project2manager.projectid = project.projectid 
GROUP BY project.title
ORDER BY Count_Manager DESC LIMIT 1;

+-----------------+-------------+
| project.title   | Cnt_Manager |
+-----------------+-------------+
| City Scape      |           8 |
+-----------------+-------------+
```

I tried to use the MAX clause but I keep getting the incorrect project title but the correct number of managers. what would be the best way to fix this?

```
SELECT title , MAX(Total) 
FROM (SELECT project.title, COUNT(project2manager.managerid) AS Total
FROM project2manager 
JOIN project ON project2manager.projectid = project.projectid 
GROUP BY project.title) AS Result;
+-------------------------+------------+
| project.title           | MAX(Total) |
+-------------------------+------------+
| Comic Con               |         8  |
+-------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Why do you specifically want to avoid using `LIMIT`?

Comment: i didn't want to hard code the result

Comment: I don't see what you mean by *hardcode the result*.

Comment: Sure, my question is unclear. For instance, if 2 rows have the same value then limit will only return one. I am unsure of what would be the best solution for this

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Now you have two answers, depending on your MySQL version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can handle top ties with `rank()`:

```
select title, cnt_manager
from (
    select 
        p.title, 
        count(*) as cnt_manager,
        rank() over(order by count(*) desc) rn
    from project2manager pm
    join project p on pm.projectid = p.projectid 
    group by p.projectid, p.title
) t
where rn = 1
```

Note that I modified your query as follows:

- unless there is a possibility that some records in `project2manager` have a `managerid` that is `null`, `count(project2manager.managerid)` can be shorten as just `count(*)`
- table aliases make the query easier to write and read
- it seems like you want to group data by project; if so, you should not realy solely on the project `title` for that - what if two different projects have the same title? To avoid that, I added `projectid` to the `group by` clause

Answer (score 0):

Try direct solution:

```
SELECT project.title, 
       COUNT(project2manager.managerid) AS Cnt_Manager
FROM project2manager 
JOIN project ON project2manager.projectid = project.projectid 
GROUP BY project.title
HAVING NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                    FROM project2manager p2m
                    JOIN project p ON p2m.projectid = p.projectid 
                    GROUP BY p.title
                    HAVING COUNT(p2m.managerid) >= Cnt_Manager )
```

For version 8+ do the same using CTE.